# How can I set&get cookie via testing Flask application with pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pytest

I can't get cookie which I have set previously via `flask.test_client`.
Just look

My fixture:

```py
    @pytest.fixture(scope='module')
    def client():
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        settings = Settings()
        ctx = app.app_context()
        ctx.push()
        with app.test_client() as client:
            yield client
        ctx.pop()
        os.system("rm -rf logs json")
```

And the test:

```py
    def test_test(client):
        # order cookie is set to url_encoded '{}' by default
        to_set = {"1": 2}
        client.set_cookie('order', json.dumps(to_set))
        print(request.cookies.get('order'))  # prints url-encoded '{}'
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to get cookie which I had set previously for testing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot an argument.
`Client.set_cookie(server_name, key, value)`

I also know
`set_cookie(key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/', domain=None, secure=False, httponly=False, samesite=None)`
.
This refers to the Flask application object itself to set cookies in your application. It is not for testing.

I can not find the original Documentation for this but looked [here](https://rallion.bitbucket.io/explorations/flask_tutorial/api/werkzeug.test.Client.html#werkzeug.test.Client.set_cookie).

The FlaskClient [flask.testing.FlaskClient](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.testing.FlaskClient) that you received from `app.test_client ()` is derived from [werkzeug.testing.Client](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/test/#werkzeug.test.Client).

The following is available in the source code of werkzeug.testing.Client.

```
def set_cookie (
         self,
         server_name,
         key,
         value = "",
         max_age = None,
         expires = None,
         path = "/",
         domain = None,
         secure = None,
         httponly = false,
         samesite = None,
         charset = "utf-8",
     )
```

(Source code files: "lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py",  "lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/testing.py").

I have a similar problem in my project. There are other questions on SO on the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890478/how-do-i-send-cookies-with-request-when-testing-flask-applications-through-noset), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838302/pass-cookie-header-with-flask-test-client-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517607/accessing-all-cookies-in-the-flask-test-response).

Comment: From docs: `Response.set_cookie(key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/', domain=None, secure=None, httponly=False)`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Perhaps this will bring us closer to the solution. I would also like to check whether within my token based authentication the respective tokens are present in the cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That decided my problem. So, the correct set_cookie request for me is `client.set_cookie('/', 'order', json.dumps(to_set))`